# ASP.NET MVC RESTful authentication API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, restful-authentication

How would I go about handling authentication in a RESTful way that will work with desktop/mobile apps? For eg. I know how to build authentication in my apps by using FormsAuthentication, which relies on cookies, which I assume only works with browsers.

Do I still use FormsAuthentication? My login method takes passwords and usernames, and I plan to use other 3rd party logins such as google, twitter and facebook.

So for the password and username, the client sends that to the server, how do I set it up so an android or windows phone 7 app can authenticate with it.

I'm also exposing some actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Dominik Bayer did a great talk at NDC 2011 about securing rest services. He discusses pros and cons of multiple ways. A good point to start from...

You have to seperate Authentication and Authorization.

If you go with multiple Login-Provider (google, facebook, twitter) then Oauth would be the choice...

But more details here:

Securing REST-Services and Web-APIs:

http://ndc2011.macsimum.no/SAL1/Torsdag/1740-1840.wmv